# Extracting only one property in List<Object> to List<String>

Tags: c#

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<String>> GetUsersAsStringBysearch(string userSearch)
        {
           //This returns List<UserTable>
            var item = await riskDBContext.UserTables.Where(e => e.Email.Contains(userSearch)).ToListAsync(); ;
            List<string> m_oEnum = new List<string>();
            foreach (var user in item)
            {
                m_oEnum.Add(user.Email);
            }
            //this is when we fullyindex the table
            //var item = await riskDBContext.UserTables.Where(x => EF.Functions.FreeText(x.Email,userSearch)).ToListAsync();

            return m_oEnum;
        }
```

> var item = await riskDBContext.UserTables.Where(e =>
> e.Email.Contains(userSearch)).ToListAsync(); ;

returns `List<UserTable>`, I want only the email id as an `List<string>`

Is there a one line statement to achieve, instead of looping the List and adding it to a `List<String>`

Comment: You could write it as `return item.Select(user => user.Email)`, but note that internally it works the same as your code. So it's just syntactic one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.Select(e => e.Email)` to create a projection

Comment: @OP: _"to create a projection"_ - that part is actually important. That means it will be included in the construction of the SQL statement and performed on the Database. It will reduce transferred data size drastically (and all that comes with that).